# Sidekiq with active job or worker

Tags: sidekiq

I am trying to send emails from my app using sidekiq.
after going through docs I could understand is we are configure the activejob to use sidekiq
with
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq

My problem is,
I am using one mailer with 3 different methods to send 3 different emails
how should I configure it?
Like should I have separate Jobs/workers for each email method?
And which is optimized way to use active job or sidekiq worker?

```
class TestMailer < ApplicationMailer
      def register(customer)
        @customer = customer
        mail(to: @customer.email, subject: 'TEST')
      end

      def success(customer)
        @customer = customer
        mail(to: @customer.email, subject: 'TEST2')
      end
    end
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Benchmarks show that Active Job is 2-20x times slower pushing jobs to
> Redis and has ~3x the processing overhead (with Rails 5.1.4 and
> Sidekiq 5.1.1). As with all benchmarks performance can change from
> version to version, YMMV.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Active-Job